# How to get the last token from the string split by a pattern

Tags: java, string

I am having a string

```
String S1="Hello@world@today@2018/01/01"
S2="Foo@Obj@new@tornado"
```

I want to get the last token always from each of these strings. Eg: 2018/01/01 in S1 and tornado in S2.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried and what error or unwanted output have you got while trying?

Answer (score 1):

If @ is a common delimiter you could do

```
String[] parts = S1.split("@");
final String lastItem = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Or, perhaps an easier way of doing it depending on your preference:

```
final String lastItem = S1.substring(S1.lastIndexOf("@"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function on String object for which you want last token

```
 public static String getTocken(String s) {
    String []str=s.split("@");
    return str[str.length-1];
}
```

Pass the input String and get the result.

Answer (score 0):

use regex and replaceAll

```
.*@
```

```
S1.replaceAll(".*@", "");
S2.replaceAll(".*@", "");
```

**output**

```
2018/01/01
tornado
```